# Determining Sign of Partial Derivatives From Level Curves

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am asked to determine whether the first and second partial derivatives are positive, negative or zero based off of the following level curves.

I am thinking $f_x$ is positive as the level curves increase as $x $ increases; $f_{xx}$ negative as the distance between the level curves increase as $x$ increases; $f_y$ negative because the level curves decrease as $y$ increases; and $f_{yy}$ is positive because the distance between the level curves decrease as $y$ increases. I am having difficulty however. Any feedback would be much appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I would agree with your assessment.

Comment: Thank you. I have to submit this to an online program and it is not liking this answer. At this point, I can't see what else it could be!

Comment: Sorry, I think $f_{yy}$ should be negative. As you go in the positive $y$ direction, the contours become closer together. The whole function looks concave.

Comment: Is $f_{xy}$ asked for?  You might try creating a function that has level curves like this and just computing directly.  I think $f(x,y) = \ln(x+y+7)$ would work.